# WiFi Signal Strength & Link Quality Excellent But Low Speed?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have 2 WiFi adapters that I use to get connection around. When both are hooked up I have very good signal and link quality, But when I have speed of 11 Mbps?

2 WiFi Adapters:

- ALFA AWUS036H
- ALFA AWUS036NHR

I'm using a 7 dBi panel antenna that came with the product, I also have a 9 dBi and a 5 dBi omni antenna that I also have that came with it. Do I Need a better antenna or is the router bad?

Comment: To be able to answer this question, it is necessary to see the output of the comman "sudo iw dev wlan0 scan". Could you pls post it?

Comment: Sure. Ill post it in a bit!